# Find a vector equation $r(t)$ for the line through point $(-9,-2,5)$ which is normal to the surface at $(-9,-2,5)$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Can someone help me on this? I don't know which equations to use. I don't understand what they mean by "surface".

Comment: is there any specification of surface? If not it's essentially a line passing through that point with direction cosines same as that normal to a surface. Usually a plane is defined in terms of it's normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not specified any surface, i will assume that it's arbitrary surface and continue my calculation to find a normal.

Let use assume a surface with equation $z=f(x,y)$ 
Then any point, on the surface is given by a vector.

$\vec {R}(x,y)=x \hat i+y \hat j + f(x,y) \hat k$

Now, to define normal vector at any point we need two tangent vector, which we can give by partial differentiating with respect to the two parameters , here they are $(x,y)$, If you have trouble seeing $(x,y)$ as parameters substitute $(u,v)$ instead of them.

$\frac{\partial \vec {R}(x,y)}{\partial x}= \hat i+ f_x(x,y) \hat k$

$\frac{\partial \vec {R}(x,y)}{\partial y}= \hat j+ f_y(x,y) \hat k$

now that we got our tangent vector specified, it's easy to specify normal at any point on the curve. Which is just cross product of these two vector.

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        \hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
        1 & 0 & f_x \\
        0 & 1 & f_y \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

$\vec n=-f_x \hat i-f_y \hat j+ \hat k$ , please note this is a normal vector, not normal unit vector.

Hence your equation of line should be.

$$\frac{x+9}{-f_x(-9,-2)}=\frac{y+2}{-f_y(-9,-2)}=\frac{z-5}{1}$$

Thus vector equation of line $\lambda$ ,$\;\;\;$$\vec r=-9\hat i -2 \hat j +5 \hat j + \lambda(-f_x(-9,-2)\hat i - f_y(-9,-2)\hat j + \hat k)$

Another thing that is provided is that, $(-9,-2,5)$ is a point on the surface $z=f(x,y)$

Comment: what did u partially differentiate if they gave no equation?

Comment: There are two parameters, to an arbitrary surface, first of all consider a single parameter curve, for example $f(x)=x$ , when you differentiate this wrt x, you get a slope of tangent. It's just similar with surfaces, but it's like you have vector here, now the thing is. AT any point on a surface there can be infinite tangents. But to define our normal we only need two of them, that can be conveniently found from our two parameters, in direction of our parameters. I have partially differentiation the vector R WRT scalar $(x,y)$ respectively. They represent our two tangent vector at that point.

Comment: In any direction though, they need not be perpendicular or anything.